# Is it possible to find a surjection from any set to the interval $[0,1]$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it possible to find a surjection from any set to the interval $[0,1]$?

If the answer is 'no' is that because it's impossible to list all the elements of $[0,1]$ or $\aleph_1$ ?

Comment: $\{0,1\}$ is a set of two points, in "my" notation. What is it in yours?

Comment: Do you mean [0,1]?

Comment: yes i mean [0,1]

Comment: No matter whether you mean $\{0,1\}$ or $[0,1]$ you can't find a surjection from _the empty set_ to it.

Comment: If your set has cardinality less than $\aleph_1$ you can not find a surjective map.

Answer (score 1):

No, and sort of.

One reason is because $[0,1]$ is uncountable: that means there's no surjection $\mathbb{N} \to [0,1]$. There are other reasons: for example, it's impossible to find a surjection from $\emptyset$, or from $\{0\}$, to $[0,1]$.

You've also assumed the continuum hypothesis in claiming that the cardinality of $[0,1]$ is $\aleph_1$.

Answer (score 0):

No. Of course not. $\varnothing$ is the empty set, and the only set that has a surjection from the empty set is $\varnothing$.

Assuming the axiom of choice, any two cardinals are comparable, and comparing them using surjections is the same comparing them using injections. So any set can be mapped onto $[0,1]$ if and only if it has cardinality of at least $2^{\aleph_0}$.

This has nothing to do with being able to "list" the elements. I will take the meaning of "list" here as enumerate using the natural numbers as the index set—i.e., that a set which can be listed is countable—also a countably infinite set cannot have a surjection onto it from a finite set, and in fact $\varnothing$ is a counterexample to either case: if a set is non-empty, there is no surjection from $\varnothing$ onto the set, and if a set is non-empty then there is no function (surjective or otherwise) from it to the empty set.

I should also add that $\aleph_1$ is the least uncountable cardinal, which may or may not be equal to the cardinality of $[0,1]$ (which is $2^{\aleph_0}$, and therefore *at least* $\aleph_1$). Since $\aleph_1$ is the cardinality of the set of countable ordinals, we can certainly list a set of size $\aleph_1$, but the indexing will now be larger than just $\Bbb N$.